# Java generic captures and comparable

Tags: java, generics

This is an implementation of a container that can be compared to any other container with a compatible key. I have a weird error using generics in Java, any ideas?

```
    private static class Container
    <Key extends Comparable<? super Key>, Value>
    implements Comparable<Container<? super Key, ?>> 
    {
        public Key key;
        public Value value;
        public Container(Key k, Value v) {
            key = k;
            value = v;
        }
        public int compareTo(Container<? super Key, ?> o) {
            return key.compareTo(o.key);
        }
    }
    ...
```

This is the error:

```
    compareTo(capture#98 of ? super Key) in
    java.lang.Comparable<capture#98 of ? super Key> cannot be applied to 
    (java.lang.Comparable<? super capture#822 of ? super Key>)
            return key.compareTo(o.key);
                      ^
    1 error
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it, the problem is that the **?** do not match the same type, but still does not know how to solve it. I want to require that each container class be comparable to any other container that has a compatible key type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but looks like a hack:

```
    private static class Container
    <K extends Comparable<? super K>, Value>
    implements Comparable<Container<? extends Comparable<? super K>, ?>>
    {
        public K key;
        public Value value;
        public Container(K k, Value v) {
            key = k;
            value = v;
        }
        public int compareTo(Container<? extends Comparable<? super K>, ?> o) {
            return -o.key.compareTo(key);
        }
    }
```

I would certainly prefer to write `key.compareTo(o.key)`, but I didn't manage to write the necessary generic constraint for that... :(

Answer (score 5):

PECS: Producer extends, Consumer super.

Let's work backwards from the compareTo method. You want to compare to a container, and you want to compare using the keys (hence key.compareTo(o.key)). This means that your `o` must produce a `Key`, and your `key` must consume a `Key`. The first part means your method declaration should be `public int compareTo(Container<? extends Key, ?> o)`, which then means you should implement `Comparable<Container<? extends Key, ?>>`. The second part means your `Key` should be a `Comparable<? super Key>`, which is how you had it.

```
private static class Container<Key extends Comparable<? super Key>, Value>
                    implements Comparable<Container<? extends Key, ?>> {

    public Key key;
    public Value value;

    public Container(Key k, Value v) {
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }

    public int compareTo(Container<? extends Key, ?> o) {
        return key.compareTo(o.key);
    }
}
```

Edit:
Following exactly the comments below, the declaration would be a follows. Notice the flip in the keys calling compareTo, and how `Key` no longer needs to implement Comparable at all. You just need to take a `Container` that can produce some key that can consume a `Key`

```
private static class Container<Key, Value> implements
        Comparable<Container<? extends Comparable<? super Key>, ?>> {

    //fields and constructors...

    public int compareTo(Container<? extends Comparable<? super Key>, ?> o) {
        return -o.key.compareTo(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont totally agree with this, but perhaps I didn't understood it. The way I see it, your `Container` is comparable to any other container that has a key *derived* from the key of the first one. I wanted a contaner to be comparable to any other container that has a key *comparable* to the key of the first one.

Comment: @Helltone: Given that you want the key of the other one to be comparable to the key of the first one, the key of the first one does not actually need to be comparable (although it probably will be). Edited above answer.

Comment: this is what I did in the answer that I posted, but I'm not actually happy with the **-o.**`key.compareTo`

Answer (score 1):

You're simply not implementing the interface correctly.  You define `Container` as implementing `Comparable<Pair<? super Key, Value>`.  That means that it must declare a method:

```
public int compareTo(Comparable<Pair<? super Key, Value> o)
```

but right now it doesn't, because it's missing the wildcard.

The problem in a broader sense is with your wildcard matching.  The `?` means "any type that matches these bounds".  Critically, different instances of `?` **can be different concrete types**; this is what the "capture of" types refer to.

Any time that you have question marks that you want to "pair up" at all, you should give that parameter a name so you can enforce the identity (e.g. introduce a generic parameter for the method).  Whenever you use a `?`, you're essentially saying that "I don't care at *all* what the concrete type of this parameter is", so you can't perform any operations that depend on matching parameters exactly (such as assignment).

---

Edit: in a more specific sense I think your intentions are slightly off.  You've tried to declare a `Container` on a particular `Key` type as comparable to a Container on a different (superclass) of `Key`.  I'm not convinced this is necessarily a good idea, as it introduces some asymmetry.

For instance, you're trying to make it so a `Container<String>` can be compared against a `Container<Object>`.  But doing the comparison the other way round wouldn't even *compile*.  Does this situation seem valid to you?  I'd expect comparability to be symmetric, and it would confuse me that `a.compareTo(b)` is 1, but `b.compareTo(a)` *doesn't* return -1 but instead refuses to compile.  This is why, for example Double implements `Comparable<Double>` and not `Comparable<? super Double>`.

**EDIT** for plain answer: So you should get rid of those wildcards, as it's not going to be possible to compare against an arbitrary object.  Thus the definition would look like:

```
private static class Container
<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>
implements Comparable<Container<Key, ?>>
{
    ...

    public int compareTo(Container<Key, ?> o) {
        return key.compareTo(o.key);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do I give a parameters a name?

Comment: `private <T super Key> static class MyStructure <Key extends Comparable<T>, Value>` defines the new parameter type `T`.

Comment: Declare a method something like `private <T super Key> method(Comparable<Pair<T, Value>>)`.  This will accept anything that `Comparable<Pair<? super Key, Value>>` would match, but now you have the `T` label that can be used throughout the method.  Multiple references to `T` refer to the same type, in contrast to multiple references to `?` which always refer to different types.

Comment: See also the generic methods tutorial for more information: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: I get compiler errors for this syntax. `private <T super Key> static class Container <Key extends Comparable<T>, Value> implements Comparable<Containerr<T, ?>>`

Comment: Can you please answer the question with the changes? I tried to apply and get compiler error.

Comment: Yeah, that'll fail as the parameter for `Comparable` won't be in its bounds (`T` could be `Object`, for example).  I didn't sketch out the example intending it to actually work for copy-and-pasting - it was merely an indication of what a generic method would look like, as a way of naming generic parameters.

Comment: @Andrzej So, can you please develop your comment into an actual answer?

Comment: I thought the actual answer was pretty obvious from the latter half, but I've added a code sample regardless.

Answer (score -3):

For some reason, Eclipse inserts "? super Type" when you create a `Comparable` type but that doesn't make sense (which superclass of Type will work in the `compareTo()`?).

Just get rid of "? super" and it will compile.